# How can I make the define the table name of an sql statement in php?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to set the table name in my sql statement in PHP

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM ?");
$stmt->execute([$table]);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

with what i tried i get: Fatal error: `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation`
If you know any solution to pass the table name in php it'll be very helpful! thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't because you can't parameterize table names. Whether you even should is another question. You would have to use dynamic SQL, be careful, makes sure to quote the name, and don't take it from user input

Comment: ah! this is a tragedy of the maximum scale

Comment: Thank you! i'll search what's dynamic sql

Comment: Why do you need to vary the table name? Often this is a symptom of a flaw in the database design.